# Is there anyway to make angular warn me when using undeclared directive in a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are times when I made a typo on the angular directive's name or the element tag in its template.

But, the only feedback I get is unexpected disappearance of the directive.

It would we nice if angularjs can warn me that I'm trying to use an undeclared directive, so I would be noticed about the typo.

This is not a very frustrating problem, but it can reduce a lot of time finding and fixing these trivial problems.

Idea: Angular should warn any non-html tag used in an app that has not been declared with angular.directive(..), though this function should be able to be selectively turned off.

Comment: Make an enhancement request https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues

Comment: You can use angular-hint.

Read more : http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/11/06/exploring-angular-1.3-angular-hint.html

Answer (score 1):

Create unit tests to verify your directives render what is expected.

For instance if you use Jasmine...

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    mockScope = $rootScope.$new();
    compileService = $compile;
}));

...

it('Renders what I want', function () {
    //Arrange
    var element = compileService('<div my-directive></div>')(mockScope);
    //Act
    mockScope.$digest();
    //Assert
    expect(element.html()).toContain("expected content");
});
```